# d3 clock text upside down

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

[image]

How can I have all numbers from 13 - 11 not rotated? (I'd like all of them be displayed in current positions, but without rotating them - as here: http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/6475678)

This is my code right now:

```
var xTick = xAxis
        // .selectAll("g")
        .selectAll(".radial")
        .data(x.ticks(24))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + ((x(d)) * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + innerRadius + ",0)";
        });

      xTick.append("line")
        .attr("x2", -5)
        .attr("stroke", "#595D5C");

      xTick.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var angle = x(d.key);
        return ((angle < Math.PI / 2) || (angle > (Math.PI * 3 / 2))) ? "rotate(90)translate(0,0)" : "rotate(-90)translate(0, -15)"; })
          .text(function(d) {
          return d;
      })
      .style("font-size", 10)
      .attr("color", "#595D5C")
      .attr("opacity", 1)
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide full code listing, not only short excerpt. I think that you should use something like that for numbers: xAxis.selectAll("text").data(x.ticks(24)).enter().append("text").attr('x',function(d){
               var angle = x(d);
      return innerRadius*Math.sin(angle);
     })
     .attr('y',function(d){
      var angle = x(d);
      return -innerRadius*Math.cos(angle);
     });
I'm not sure that there is no error because I didn't see full code. But the idea is that you should use x and y attr instead of appending to transform-rotated xTick.

Comment: This is not working for me.. Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/wMgghG6U